# How to throttle Microsoft OSQL / SQLCMD without installing any additional tools?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there way to throttle a query executed by [Microsoft OSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) so that it runs at a lower priority in the background while minimally affecting the performance of a server?

I am running a *single* large filtered `SELECT` statement (not multiple with lots of GOs) that will extract a large number of rows and have it working in OSQL today just fine and have a scheduled process to kick it off. The process though sometimes collides with other processes *(both user and automated that are triggered)* and fights for I/O *(primarily disk which I can't immediately solve)* which slows both processes down and triggers timeouts on those other processes.

I want it to run at the lowest of priority of other database functions without the process aborting or being killed off.

I am aware there is the `-t` OSQL parameter which I believe if you do not set it it will not terminate due to timeout. As well as there is the `-a` packet size parameter which talks about performance but not sure how effective it is in throttling and seams like it may even have the opposite effect.

We run app white listing on the systems and it is very difficult to get any other tools approved that might accomplish this so I am trying to focus on Microsoft provided tools.

**Question:**

Is there a feature **built into** Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Windows 2008, or part of supported Microsoft suite *(including MSDN)* or later that the standard installation of SQL Server and SSRS would facilitate **some sort of throttling** of the *SQLCMD* command or potentially a stored procedure it executes? Alternatively if there is a function in OSQL that does this please provide an example and explanation.

Comment: Side note: `osql` and `isql` are deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 - you should use `sqlcmd` instead (only `sqlcmd` has access to all the new features that newer SQL Server versions bring us)

Comment: @marc_s  Thanks.. I was looking at our old doc, we use 2008 (but may be in compatibility mode) I will update question to reflect this.

Comment: What blocks are you experiencing? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Namphibian Updated description, short verison I/O constraints.